# "Don't let dog out" vs "don't let the dog out"

Tags: grammaticality, definite-article, proper-nouns

> Don't let dog out.

> Don't let *the* dog out.

Are those sentences both valid, or is only the latter a valid one?

Is *the* needed for non-proper nouns?
Is "Don't let Mike out." valid?

Comment: Welcome Matt! You kind of answered your own question in a way - "Don't let dog out" would work if the dog's name is "Dog", which is why "Don't let Mike out" is correct. There's likely a rule or even a duplicate question out there for this.  Did you do a search on the site?

Comment: I came from StackOverflow. I am not really sure how to search grammar questions... programmer -->

Comment: Clearly the "the" is required. I've never chanted "Who let dogs out? Who! Who who, who who!" before.

Comment: To me it appears from your question that you got proper nouns and common nouns exactly backwards. So before there's any misunderstanding: *dog* is a common noun, or what you call "non-proper". *Mike* is a proper noun. Proper nouns quite typically don't take articles, though some can, and others still actually can't appear without, like "the Sun". That being said, in its current form this looks like a question for ELL, not ELU.

Answer (score 1):

'Don't let *the* dog out' is the correct version.

When you are dealing with common nouns, you usually need to provide an article ('a', 'an' or 'the').  When dealing with proper nouns ('Mike' 'France' 'Fido') you don't use an article.

So:

> Don't let Fido out

or

> Don't let **the** dog out.